# how to check if input field is empty on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery so i wonder how can i show error message after i click submit button only if an input field is empty.

Below the code my simple form how to apply to it.

```
<form id="myid" name="myid" method="post" action="hook.php">

name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

age : <input type="text" name="age" id="age">

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />

</form>
```

I would like to show error like this

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone has already mentioned, you should probably look to use an external library for validation. That said, this seems like it might work [(see JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6sLp/):

```
var $form = $("#myid"),
    $errorMsg = $("<span class='error'>This field is required..!!</span>");

$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    // If any field is blank, we don't submit the form
    var toReturn = true;
    $("input", $form).each(function () {
        // If our field is blank
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            // Add an error message
            if (!$(this).data("error")) {
                $(this).data("error", $errorMsg.clone().insertAfter($(this)));
            }
            toReturn = false;
        }
        // If the field is not blank
        else {
            // Remove the error message 
            if ($(this).data("error")) {
                $(this).data("error").remove();
                $(this).removeData("error");
            }
        }
    });
    return toReturn;
});
```

Comment: this is complete perfect ~ thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use event.preventDefault to stop the default action happening. Then check your condition, display errors if the condition fails and submit the form if not.

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($(this).val().length === 0) {
    // display some error  
  } else {
    $("#myid").submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Really I advice you to use some frameworks for form validation. Because that's the common task and it was already done 100000 times before. There are plenty of it, for example [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) or [Jquery plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), but there are a lot of others which is simple and easily maintainable, just google 'javascript form validation'

Why is already implemented code better than custom in that case: 1) It already written, tested and working, 2) You almost never need only single validation, and really to validate form for several parameters could be a challenge and could lead to a big amount of validation code 3) framework is DRYer and a really a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I also advise you to use validation framework because you need more validation for different field. Use MooTools Floor this is most reliable framework for validation.
[MooTool Floor](http://mootools.floor.ch/en/labs/formcheck/forum-registration/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HTML5 `required='required'` option in the input tag...